# How should I update redux store during a react-router transition?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm facing an issue on how to update store when a react-router transition occurs.

In my current implementation (below), update store before rendering next page. The issue comes up when the current page gets a store update based on the data for the next page: (1) the current page renders pointlessly (it's subscribed to store updates), because the updated store is for the next page (2) the current page breaks on render because updated store only has data for the next page.

```
superagent
  .get(opts.path)
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end((err, res) => {
    let pageData = res && res.body || {};
    store.dispatch(setPageStore(pageData));
    render(store);
  });
```

The reverse is problematic too, render next page before updating store. The issue now is the next page breaks on render because the data needed for the next page is not there until store is updated.

I'm either misusing the libraries, or my architecture is incomplete, or something else. help!

The rest of the sample code:

### app

```
const React = require('react');
const Router = require('react-router');
const {createStore} = require('redux');
const {update} = React.addons;
const routes = require('./routes'); // all the routes
let store = {};
let initialLoad = true;

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (Handler, opts) => {
  if(initialLoad) {
    initialLoad = false;

    // hydrate
    const initialState = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-state').text);
    store = createStore(appReducer, initialState);
    render(store);

  } else {
    superagent
      .get(opts.path)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end((err, res) => {
        let pageData = res && res.body || {};
        store.dispatch(setPageStore(pageData));
        render(store);
      });
  }
});

function render(store) {
  React.render(
    <Provider store={store} children={() => <Handler/>} />, 
    document.getElementById('react')
  );
}
```

### action & reducer

```
function appReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_PAGE_STORE':
      return update(state, {$merge: action.pageData});

    default:
      return reduce(state, action);
  }
}

const reduce = combineReducers({
  // ..all the reducers
});

function setPageStore(pageData) {
  return {type: 'SET_PAGE_STORE', pageData};
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware to dispatch multiple actions one after another

See the awesome [redux doc #Async Actions section](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) for more!

So your fetch data action creator will look something like this:

```js
function fetchSomeData(path) {
  return dispatch => {
    // first dispatch a action to start the spinner
    dispatch(fetchStarted(path))

    return superagent.get(path)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          dispatch(fetchDataError(err)) // handle error
        } else {
          let pageData = res && res.body || {};
          dispatch(fetchSuccess(pageData)); // do whatever you want when fetch is done here
          // such as this action from redux-simple-router to change route
          dispatch(pushPath('/some/path'))
      });
  }
}
```

As you can see, by simply doing `store.dispatch(fetchSomeData('somePath'))`, it will automatically first call `fetchStarted` to show spinner, and when the process is done, call `fetchSuccess(path)` to hide spinner, update state, rerender...etc, or call `fetchError(err)` to show an error message, and you can call actions to change routes anywhere in this process!

(you don't need redux-simple router if you don't like it, you can call `history.pushState(null, '/some/path')` to change route, I just found redux-simple-router really handy, because you don't need to pass the history everywhere, plus you have a `UPDATE_PATH` action you can listen to if you want to track route changes)

---

Furthermore, I recommend [`redux-simple-router`](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router) when you use react-router with redux, it allows you to watch route changes with the `UPDATE_PATH` action type, and `pushPath` action to change route.
Also, I notice you're using an out-dated version of react-router...

If you want to use the latest version of react-router with redux-simple-router (together with redux-thunk), [check out this repo](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)!

you can find its store configuration, router setup in these files:

```js
src/main.js                 // calls reactDOM.render(<Root />, ...) to render <Root />
src/containers/Root.js      // <Root /> is a wrapper for react-redux <Provider />
src/redux/configureStore.js // store configuration, how redux-thunk middleware is configured
src/routes/index.js         // routes are defined here
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to make your pages compatible with having incomplete data, until the new page data is fetched. Then you could push the new path, and it would render immediately as much as it could, and your UI components render spinners (or something equivalent) until the data for the next page is fetched and dispatched to the store. On the second pass, the page would be re-rendered fully.

The other thing that comes to mind is that ideally, the shape of your store is such that all your pages are fundamentally compatible with all possible states that it could be in, without conflict. That will let you do things like prefetching data, which could unlock ways to minimize transition time, and to cache previous views. After all, single-page architecture isn't especially useful when it still requires a round-trip.